# input=file should display filename instead of "No file Selected" AFTER re-loading or save/submit

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload

I have a input=file field and bunch of input=text fields on my page which is kind of a settings page. Once I save the settings, all the input=text fields are populated with their values BUT input=file field shows as "No file selected" even when a json file was already uploaded.

I want to indicate in some way that a file was uploaded, I tried onchange function to display file name but it works only when I browse and select a file.

What can I do to show that a file has been uploaded and show it's name instead of "No file selected"?

I want to achieve this using javascript.

Comment: It's not possible to pre-load a file input, for security reasons. The file has to be selected by the user.

Comment: @Barmar is there a way I can still display filename? Maybe by getting it from server-side?

Comment: You could display it in a DIV or SPAN next to the input. If you display it in the input, the user will expect the file to be uploaded the next time the form is submitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

following code works with JSP tags, from server side I sent the value isFileSelected which is used to override "No file Selected" by "File is Uploaded" and file upload functionality works as is.

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="$(isFileSelected == 1)">
<td><input=file size="48" style="width:70px;color:transparent;" onchange="displayFileName(this.value)"/><span id="fileStatus">File is Uploaded</span></td>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<td><input=file size="48"/></td>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
 

function displayFileName(fakePath){
document.getElementById("fileStatus").innerHTML = fakePath.replace("C:\\fakepath\\","");
}
```